# Is it possible to see a feed of my followed games?

Tags: steam

This is strange. I've looked everywhere (community hub, profile, news page, email, etc.), but I can't find an actual feed of updates from my followed games. The closest thing I've found is [this page](https://store.steampowered.com/updated/myapps/), but this is specifically for games in your library. It has nothing to do with followed games.

This means that the only way for me to see an update is to just *happen* to be sitting at my computer the exact moment steam pushes the desktop notification. And if I *miss* that notification (which I will), I'll never know about it unless I spontaneously decide to *manually* go to the community hub of every single game on my [followed list](https://steamcommunity.com/id/bradenbest/followedgames/) and scrub through the latest news, which isn't even listed in a linear format. It's listed in some weird "staggered grid" format. Time consuming.

This is kind of ridiculous. I thought the function of "following" something was that you get a feed of recent updates that you can look at on your own time, whether via email or a dedicated feed. They make *damn* sure that you know about every sale, from launching a big news window when you start the client, to throwing a huge ad on the front page, to emailing you when a wishlisted item goes on sale, etc. But nothing for followed games? What's the point of following them if I *still* have to manually visit the community hub (and have no idea if the game I'm looking at has actually updated until the page loads)?

Surely I must be missing something?

In any case, I've been trying to find this elusive feed for *months* with no luck. I would really like to actually make use of this feature (assuming it actually exists).

Comment: I tried hard not to rant in my question, but I'm so floored about this that I don't know what else to say other than to express my bewilderment.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can find a feed of updates of the games you follow under '**Activity**', which is accessible under your profile name in the menu (in both the browser and client version).

[image: A screenshot of Steam with the location of 'Activity' highlighted]

**You can adjust the feed in 'Friend Activity Settings'**, at the top (partially visible in the screenshot).

Updates are part of 'announcements', and to see only those, choose that option in the settings:

[image: Friend Activity Settings->A group I belong to:->Posts an announcement]

Comment: Geez, that is unintuitive. Is there a way to filter it down to only updates from followed games?

Comment: They are, in that same display of lucidity, in all probability part of the 'announcement' setting: "A group I belong to", option "Posts an announcement?". Edit: Added to the answer.

Comment: Oh man, it *is*. I just tested it out. I should apply for a job at valve and fix their UI. One of the things I would add: a 'remove from wishlist' button on the store page :P

Comment: They used to have that, I know realize. Not even that long ago you could just re-click the 'Wishlist' button a title's page to remove it. Silly to remove that function: do they really think users will get so upset having to scroll through their wish list that they might just buy the game eventually :)?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the followed games from "Your Store" and then "Followed Games & Software"

[image: Your Store-Followed Games & Software]

Regards

Answer (score -1):

I found out a way to see all of your followed games, in case you were wondering; go to your nametage at the top of the screen, and click "Activity" in the drop-down menu. Then, on the right side of your screen, you should see a box with your profile and some buttons. Click "Games." (It has an image of a mouse on it) Now all that's left is to click the "followed" tab at the top, and bam! A list of all your followed games. Hopefully that is helpful to you!

Comment: This seems helpful. Are you able to provide a screenshot or two so it is easier to follow these steps?

Comment: My question [specifically mentions this page and why it's not ideal](https://imgur.com/EScT10g). Be sure to read the question details before answering.